# Radius through input

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I wonder if I could provide some help to make a map application with input and display a 3km radius of the specified location.
thank you very much.
sorry for my bad English (jejeje)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is geocode an address and plant a circle around it. Keep in mind that you have to bind a Google Map to a DOM element, which is this sample code is a div with an id of "map".

```
function geocodeAndMap(address) {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: results[0].geometry.location,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions); 

      var addressMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });

      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        map: map,
        radius: 3000,
        fillColor: '#660000'
      });
      circle.bindTo('center',addressMarker,'position');
  });
}
```